# Click event not firing on a listview in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, click, jquery-mobile

I've got a jquery mobile 1.0b1 website that populates a list via ajax.

After the list is populated I call

```
$('#theResults').listview();
```

The resulting HTML has the links each with a class "sresult" - what follows is a sample

```
<li><a class='sresult' href="#addResult">

                    <h3>title</h3>

                    <p>some content</p>


            </a></li>
```

Now I have a live function that should THEORETICALLY bind a click event to these items. It works find in firefox... however on safari on my iPhone the click event does not fire

```
        $('.sresult').live('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("i'm running!");
        });
```

Comment: You're missing a period: `$('.sresult')`

Comment: yeah a typo in my stackoverflow entry... it didn't address the issue... i updated my question above. good eye though

Comment: for now i added href='javascript:stub()'  and added a function called stub that does nothing. This seems to allow the event to get attached on the iPhone... it kind of sucks as a solution. I would like to know how to do it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try vclick ( search for vclick http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/globalconfig.html )

```
$('.sresult').live('vclick', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("i'm running!");
});
```

instead of

```
$('.sresult').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("i'm running!");
});
```